# Deep Belief Networks: connecting visible bias of higher layers to hidden bias of lower layer?

Tags: restricted-boltzmann-machine, deep-belief-networks

Suppose we are building a DBN (Deep Belief Network) and we have already trained some lower layers as Restricted Bolzmann Machines.
Now we add a new layer, with new weights and new biases for the new hidden nodes.

Do we use the biases of the hidden nodes of the previous layer as the biases of the 'visible' nodes of the new layer? Or should I create separate bias terms unrelated to the bias terms of the previous layer?